# Delete multiple value from database

Tags: php, mysql, delete-row

I am using this file to delete record from server

```
<?php

$dbhandle = mysql_connect("localhost", "admin", "admin") or die(mysql_error()) ; 
$selected =  mysql_select_db("dbname" ,$dbhandle) or die(mysql_error()) ; 


$id=$_POST['id'];

foreach($id as  $value)
{

 $query = mysql_query("DELETE FROM `record` WHERE `id`=$value");
}
 mysql_close($dbhandle);
?>
```

but i am unable to delete record from the database. query is executing without any error but it cannot delete records from table

Comment: Be sure to escape $value as it is user provided and subject to injection.  Better yet, use a prepared statement with PDO.

Comment: clearly `$id` is returning wrong values, as syntax is fine

Comment: Agree with younis.  Before you do your query, execute `echo('<pre>'.print_r($_POST,1).'</pre>');` and see what it looks like.

Comment: $id is returning right values @younis

Comment: can you show the values? @teamdigifizz

Answer (score 3):

```
$query = mysql_query('DELETE FROM `record` WHERE `id` IN (' . implode(',', array_map('intval', $id)) . ')');
```

Comment: This also solves OP's SQL injection vulnerability. Please elaborate on what is happening here, i.e. removal of `foreach` in place of this, the array value casting/sanitizing, and the performance improvement from not running multiple queries.

Comment: The MySQL extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0. You should consider using MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extensions instead.

Comment: That wasn't his question though!

Comment: @younis.  Probably, but it wasn't stated in the question.  Maybe they are UUID's.

Answer (score 0):

This will work even if `$id` array doesn't contain integers.

```
class db {
    private static $instance = NULL;
    private function __construct() {}   //Make private
    private function __clone(){}   //Make private
    public static function db() //Get instance of DB
    {
        if (!self::$instance)
        {
            self::$instance = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=myDB;charset=utf8",'myUsername','myPassword',array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES=>false,PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY=>true,PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE=>PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE=>PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }
}

if(count($ids)) {  //Make sure you don't have an empty data set.
  $qMarks = str_repeat('?,', count($ids)-1) . '?';
  $sql ="DELETE FROM `record` WHERE `id` IN ({$qMarks})";
  $stmt = $db::db->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->execute($id);
}
```